# Erase Label Constraints

Tags: java, swing, constraints, jlabel

I named a custom Label MyLabel, and it works somewhat odd. MyLabel is a Label, which just extended JLabel.

```
public class MyLabel extends JLabel {
    public MyLabel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyLabel(String arg0) {
        super(arg0);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyLabel(Icon arg0) {
        super(arg0);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyLabel(String arg0, int arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyLabel(Icon arg0, int arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

    public MyLabel(String arg0, Icon arg1, int arg2) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

As you see, nothing has added. But, here's weird thing. Whenever I add MyLabel class Label, the last one I added gets Constraints, though I didn't added!

Under is how I added Label on Contentpane.

```
MyLabel label0_1 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label0_2 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label0_3 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label0_4 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label0_0 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label1_1 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label1_2 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label1_3 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label1_4 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label1_0 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label2_1 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label2_2 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label2_3 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label2_4 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label2_0 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label3_1 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label3_2 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label3_3 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label3_4 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label3_0 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label4_1 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label4_2 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label4_3 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label4_4 = new MyLabel("");
MyLabel label4_0 = new MyLabel("");
label0_1 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label0_2 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label0_3 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label0_4 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label0_0 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label1_1 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label1_2 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label1_3 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label1_4 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label1_0 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label2_1 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label2_2 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label2_3 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label2_4 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label2_0 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label3_1 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label3_2 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label3_3 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label3_4 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label3_0 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label4_1 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label4_2 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label4_3 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label4_0 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label4_4 = new MyLabel(defaultImage);
label0_0.setBounds(120, 120, 100, 100);
label0_1.setBounds(220, 120, 100, 100);
label0_2.setBounds(320, 120, 100, 100);
label0_3.setBounds(420, 120, 100, 100);
label0_4.setBounds(520, 120, 100, 100);
label1_0.setBounds(120, 220, 100, 100);
label1_1.setBounds(220, 220, 100, 100);
label1_2.setBounds(320, 220, 100, 100);
label1_3.setBounds(420, 220, 100, 100);
label1_4.setBounds(520, 220, 100, 100);
label2_0.setBounds(120, 320, 100, 100);
label2_1.setBounds(220, 320, 100, 100);
label2_2.setBounds(320, 320, 100, 100);
label2_3.setBounds(420, 320, 100, 100);
label2_4.setBounds(520, 320, 100, 100);
label3_0.setBounds(120, 420, 100, 100);
label3_1.setBounds(220, 420, 100, 100);
label3_2.setBounds(320, 420, 100, 100);
label3_3.setBounds(420, 420, 100, 100);
label3_4.setBounds(520, 420, 100, 100);
label4_0.setBounds(120, 520, 100, 100);
label4_1.setBounds(220, 520, 100, 100);
label4_2.setBounds(320, 520, 100, 100);
label4_3.setBounds(420, 520, 100, 100);
label4_4.setBounds(520, 520, 100, 100);
frame.getContentPane().add(label0_0);
frame.getContentPane().add(label0_1);
frame.getContentPane().add(label0_2);
frame.getContentPane().add(label0_3);
frame.getContentPane().add(label0_4);
frame.getContentPane().add(label1_0);
frame.getContentPane().add(label1_1);
frame.getContentPane().add(label1_2);
frame.getContentPane().add(label1_3);
frame.getContentPane().add(label1_4);
frame.getContentPane().add(label2_0);
frame.getContentPane().add(label2_1);
frame.getContentPane().add(label2_2);
frame.getContentPane().add(label2_3);
frame.getContentPane().add(label2_4);
frame.getContentPane().add(label3_0);
frame.getContentPane().add(label3_1);
frame.getContentPane().add(label3_2);
frame.getContentPane().add(label3_3);
frame.getContentPane().add(label3_4);
frame.getContentPane().add(label4_0);
frame.getContentPane().add(label4_1);
frame.getContentPane().add(label4_2);
frame.getContentPane().add(label4_3);
frame.getContentPane().add(label4_4);
```

I added some Labels as this. Right now, label4_4 has Constraints. When I deleted label4_4, label4_3 got Constraints. And when I deleted label4_3 too, label4_2 gets it! Why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to go read [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) in particular.

A `JFrame`, by default uses a `BorderLayout`.  This means that only the last component added to any of the five available positions (`CENTER` been the default) will be managed, all other components are ignored.

The answer to your question is simple.

1. Don't use `setBounds`
2. Make use of one or more appropriate layout managers

Comment: Thanks that I found where I made a mistake. I needed to use AbsoluteLayout from the first, but I forgot it.

Comment: No, you need to use an appropriate layout manager, all you're doing is making more work for yourself

Comment: I'm doing like that for make a 5*5 sized board, so it's necessary for me. Anyway, thanks for reply.

Comment: GridLayout or GridBagLayout